# How to create git remote repository using script RHEL 7

Tags: git-remote

I apologize if this question has been asked but I could not find any answers when I  did a search.
    I am trying to create a GIT remote repository that is being hosted on our server (123.123.com) instead of gitlab.com using a script. I have found really great scripts that connected via https that I was able to tweak and get it to work in my vm @ home but that configuration is user to gitlab.com. 
    I don't know how to tweak the script to replace things like "content-type json" .... or find the API for the server. So, I think ideally the below script written by ckalima  is what I would like to use but I'm a noob to GIT and definitely scripting on a whole. https://gist.github.com/ckalima/1364886
    I replaced all the variables and it does not work. In the end, it says it creates the repo but it really doesn't. Sorry for the long post, thanks in advance. Joybells

```
# remgit.sh
# Creates a remote git repository from the current local directory

# Configuration
# Replace SSH_USERNAME, SSH_HOST, SSH_GIT_PATH with your details
USER=SSH_USERNAME
HOST=SSH_HOST
GIT_PATH=SSH_GIT_PATH

REPO=${PWD##*/}
GIT_REMOTE_URL=ssh://$USER@$HOST/$GIT_PATH/$REPO

echo "-------------------------------------------"
echo "------ Building New Git Repository --------"
echo "-------------------------------------------"

# Setup remote repo

echo "--"
echo "-- Creating bare remote repo at:"
echo "-- $USER@$HOST/$GIT_PATH/$REPO"
echo "--"

ssh $USER@$HOST 'mkdir '$GIT_PATH'/'$REPO' && cd '$GIT_PATH'/'$REPO' && git --bare init && git --bare update-server-info && cp hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update && chmod a+x hooks/post-update && touch git-daemon-export-ok'

# Configure local repo

echo "--"
echo "-- Initializing local repo & pushing to remote"
echo "--"

touch .gitignore
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git push --all $GIT_REMOTE_URL
git remote add origin $GIT_REMOTE_URL
git config branch.master.remote origin
git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
git fetch
git merge master
git branch -a

echo "--"
echo "-- Your new git repo '$REPO' is ready and initialized at:"
echo "-- $USER@$HOST/$GIT_PATH/$REPO"
echo "--"
```

Comment: You mention `it says it creates the repo but it really doesn't`.  What makes you think it really doesn't?  Can you paste the console output you see when you run this script?

Comment: So this what happens when I run the script - Xs and <> are information that I can not include in my answer.
./createrepo.sh

./createrepo.sh: line 11: git@xxxx.xxx.xxx.com:<server>/Jun18ssh: No such file or directory
-------------------------------------------
------ Building New Git Repository --------
-------------------------------------------
--
-- Creating bare remote repo at:
-- <user>@xxx.xxx.xxx.com/git@xxx.xxx.xxx.com:<user>/Jun18ssh
--
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘git@xxx.xxx.xxx.com:<user>/Jun18ssh’: No such file or directory
--

Comment: -- Initializing local repo & pushing to remote
--
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/<user>/Jun18ssh/.git/
[master (root-commit) 47d6190] initial commit
 3 files changed, 72 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 create mode 100755 createrepo.sh
 create mode 100755 gitcreate.sh
fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

    git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name

    git push <name>

usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>

Comment: -f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
    --tags                import all tags and associated objects when fetching
                          or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
    -t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
    -m, --master <branch>
                          master branch
    --mirror[=<push|fetch>]
                          set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from

fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Already up-to-date.
* master
--
-- Your new git repo 'Jun18ssh' is ready and initialized at:
-- <user>@xxx.xxx.xxx.com/git@xxx.xxx.xxx.com:<user>/Jun18ssh

Comment: I go to the link and it is invalid :-( I get the 404 error.